# Symfony 5 constructor and method params binding

Tags: symfony, service, binding, autowired

I have a problem with binding params. My code is:

```
interface MessageInterface
{
    public function getMessage() : string;
}

class MessageType1 implements MessageInterface
{

    public function getMessage(): string
    {
        return 'Type 1';
    }
}

class MessageType2 implements MessageInterface
{

    public function getMessage(): string
    {
        return 'Type 2';
    }
}

class TestController extends AbstractController
{

    private $m;

    public function __construct(MessageInterface $m)
    {
       $this->m = $m;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/message", name="message")
     */
    public function index(MessageInterface $m): Response
    {
        return $this->render('test/index.html.twig', [
            'message' => $m->getMessage(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

How to bind in service.yaml TestController constructor param to MessageType1 class and method index param to MessageType2 class ?

Comment: Lookup named aliases in the service container docs.

Comment: Are you requiring the Interface as the service for some reason? Normally you would declare the desired class name as the type-hint for the service dependency injection. `public function __construct(MessageType1 $m)` and `public function index(MessageType2 $m): Response` See [autowiring](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html)  Usually Interfaces as services are used when a single service declaration is ambiguous, such as `Psr\Log\LoggerInterface`  which can be `monolog` or a custom service of your own that implements the `Psr\Log\LoggerInterface`.

Comment: @WillB. You should run bin/console debug:container LoggerInterface sometime when you get bored.  Might be surprised at what you find.

Comment: @Cerad are referring to the [`service argument name binding`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#binding-arguments-by-name-or-type) definitions?  That was my point exactly, since the `LoggerInterface` is an ambiguous service definition.

Comment: To be perfectly honest, even after reading your comment several times, I don't understand what your point is.  The question can be solved by simply naming the arguments and then using either binding or named aliases.  Looks like a drive by question anyways.

Comment: My point was that in general using an Interface and argument name binding to declare/override the service injection makes visibility and maintainability for debugging and usages tedious, as opposed to using the type-hint autowiring approach to inject the desired service by a specific FQCN. So either `index(MessageType2 $m)` or `index(MessageInterface $m2)` and a definition in services.yaml for `bind: MessageInterface $m2: '@MessageType2'` Unless you are expecting external packages to also utilize the interface, there's not much benefit to argument name binding.

Comment: @WillB. Both Symfony and PHP has gone all in on making argument names part of the code.  I fear you may be unsuccessful in your attempt at declaring argument name binding of little value.

Comment: Thanks, I have already known how to solve it